# Vba does not recognize the variable file name

Tags: vba, variables

in order to put the date in the workbook i created I used this code.

```
Dim tarih As String
Dim dot As String
dot = "."

Dim days2 As Integer
Dim months2 As Integer
Dim years2 As Integer
days2 = Day(Date)
months2 = Month(Date)
years2 = Year(Date)

tarih = days2 & dot & months2 & dot & years2

Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\ROL_Analysis" & tarih & ".xlsx"
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized

Dim strii As String
strii = "ROL_Analysis" & tarih & ".xlsx"

Workbooks("ROL_Analysis" & tarih & ".xlsx").Activate
```

I used directly the name, after that I defined a string to put it but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: are you getting an error ? what line ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbooks.Add

Dim strii As String
strii = "ROL_Analysis" & tarih & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\Excel Before Code Templates (BCT)\" & strii & ""
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized

Workbooks(strii).Activate
```

ok this works